# Limit of the spherical Bessel function of the second kind

Tags: limits, factorial, bessel-functions

I know that the limit for the spherical bessel function of the first kind when $x<<1$ is:

$j_{n}(x<<1)=\frac{x^n}{(2n+1)!!}$

I can see this from the formula for $j_{n}(x)$ (taken from wolfram's webpage):

$j_{n}(x)=2^{n}x^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(k+n)!}{k!(2k+2n+1)!}x^{2k}$

and applying the relation: $(2n+1)!!=(2n+1)!/2^{n}n!$ . So, the formula for the spherical bessel function of the second kind is (also taken from wolfram):

$y_{n}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n}x^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}(k-n)!}{k!(2k-2n)!}x^{2k}$

The result I get for the limit $x<<1$ in this case is:

$y_n(x<<1)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-n)!}{2^{n}(-2n)!}\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$

But I don't know how to deal with these negative factorials. I think maybe I would need the relation $(2n-1)!!=(2n)!/2^{n}n!$ because in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics 2nd edition book they give a result for this in chapter 16, it is:

$y_{n}(x<<1)=-\frac{(2n-1)!}{x^{n+1}}$

The question is: how to obtain this Jackson's result?

Comment: Are you trying to find an asymptotic behavior of the spherical Bessel function?

Comment: yes, sorry for the equality symbol, I should have used "$\rightarrow$" instead

Comment: How has Jackson defined $j_l(x)$ ?

Comment: He first defines ("not spherical") Bessel functions like: $J_{n}(x)=\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!\Gamma(k+n+1)}\big(\frac{x}{2}\big)^{2k}$, and then defines spherical Bessel functions like: $j_{l}(x)=(\frac{\pi}{2x})^{1/2}J_{l+1/2}(x)$

Comment: Spend more time on it!  It is not hard

Comment: So, first of all the relation that gives Jackson is actually with $(2n-1)!!$ in the numerator (double factorial instead of single one). Second, I think maybe wolfram's relations of Bessel functions are wrong, but using the ones given in this webpage the calculation is straightforward: http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.53